# Naming inline images when sending HTML mails with Python's email.mime.multipart

Tags: python, html-email

Using python's email package I send emails with inline images. That works. Now, I want to assign actual names to these images (not html titles ..), so when downloading them they are not named *'noname'* (e.g. gmail). Code by now:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
...

# image file
msgText = MIMEText('<img src="cid:image" alt="Smiley" title="title">', 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

# In-line Image
with open('/Users/john/Desktop/2015-04-21_13.35.38.png', 'rb') as fp:
    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage)

...
server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msgRoot.as_string())
```

I tried a lot of things and also asked google plenty of times. Is it even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I think another way would be `msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read(), name = 'filename')`. Couldn't find it really anywhere, it's just something I grabbed without people mentioning that sets the name. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution and it seems to work as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

One can actually assign *Content-ID*, *Content-Type*, *Content-Transfer-Encoding* & *Content-Disposition* to one MIME-file ([check for more](http://courses.oreillyschool.com/Python2/Python2-11.html)). By so, you can just add:

```
msgImage.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='filename')
```

So, you end up having:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
...

# image file
msgText = MIMEText('<img src="cid:image" alt="Smiley" title="title">', 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

# In-line Image
with open('/Users/john/Desktop/2015-04-21_13.35.38.png', 'rb') as fp:
    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>')
msgImage.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='filename')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage)

...
server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msgRoot.as_string())
```

And you are done.

You may prefer the way mentioned by @PascalvKooten, creating the MIMEImage instance like so:

```
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read(), filename='filename')
```

Which works like charm as well.

Comment: It's indeed amazing how difficult it is to find an answer (this is a new question/answer I'm pretty sure).

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this after you mentioned the problem, it was difficult to find!

As you verified, the name can be set by:

```
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read(), name = 'filename')
```

Furthermore, I'm maintaining `yagmail`; a package that should make it easy to send emails. I included the functionality you desire, and just released a new minor update for it!

You can get `yagmail` with `pip install` (or `pip3 install` for Python 3).

Start a connection:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.Connect('username', 'password')
```

This would just send the image:

```
yag.send('someone@mail.com', contents = ['/local/or/external/image.png'])
```

It would use the default naming of the end of the path (in this case `image.png`). Though it is also possible to give an alias (everywhere aliases are done by dicts, like this: `contents = [{'/local/or/external/image.png' : 'newfilename'}]`

The package will guess the file contents on its own, that is, it will know when you're talking HTML/images/other type of content, or when you're writing text... you can all just put it into `contents`!

Another example:

```
yag.send(to = 'someone@mail.com', subject = 'Demonstration',  
         contents = ['Hey buddy, have a look at the picture below:', '/local/image.png'])
```

It has a bunch of other functionality you might find attractive, [described and maintained here](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

Comment: Thanks for the efforts adapting the code, I might have a look at the package !